# Azure Mobile Services - Can I increment a field value using table.update()?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using mobile services with JS and would like to be able to update a numeric field using syntax like:

```
var table = request.service.tables.getTable("myTable");

var testId = "417DDFA6-8BA8-481A-964B-E8A7CCB36F29";

table.update({
  id: testId,
  numericField: table.numericField + 1
}, {
  success: returnSuccess,
  error: returnError
});
```

I had fingers crossed on both hands when I ran this but got an error like:

```
Error: IMNOD: [msnodesql] Parameter 1: Invalid number parameter (SqlState: IMNOD, Code: -1)
```

Obviously this method isn't going to work but is there a way to do this (using the .update() function)?

I'd like to keep this using the tables object / structure if I can (rather than going down the sqlserver module with raw SQL route).

Comment: If you don't want to use a raw SQL UPDATE statement, you will need to query for the record first to get the existing value, increment the value, and update the record.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line:

```
  numericField: table.numericField + 1
```

You need to access a single record, then increment that.  Let's say that testId is in fact in the table:

```
var query = table.where({ id: testId });
query.read().then(function (items) {
  table.update({ id: testId, numericField: items[0].numericField + 1 }, {
    ...
  });
});
```

This is a very basic query pattern.  I'm sure there are better ways of doing this, depending on what your actual requirements are.  Check out the table.lookup() method as well as a method of getting a record.